# Unix Commands Questions - mv, pwd, chmod, and others

Tags: grep, command, mv, diff, top

I wanted to make sure Im matching the correct command to the description, including possible tags I may need and I'd really appreciate if someone could confirm them for me:

1. Show file permissions for normal and hidden files in a directory: `ls -l -a`
2. Move files from one directory to another: `mv`
3. Change a file’s permissions:  `chmod`
4. Show the absolute path of the directory you’re currently in: `pwd`
5. Looks through the names of files and folders (recursively) for a keyword: `grep`
6. Displays real-time information about processes running on the system: `top`
7. Find the difference between two files (4-letter command): `diff`

Comment: The `man` command will help you with this. For example `man mv`

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I fully understand the point of the question but this

> Looks through the names of files and folders (recursively) for a keyword: grep

is not entirely correct as `grep` will not look for folder (more
commonly known as *directory* on *nix) names and will not work
recursively without `-r` or `-R`. And - didn't you really mean `find`
here?

For the rest, you can use the tools you listed but there plenty of
alternatives which work better in some scenarios but worse in others -
for example: (1) `(shopt -s dotglob; stat *)` (this is
Bash-specific.), (2) `rsync --remove-source-files`, (5) `ag` (this one
is especially good for searching in the source code), (6) `htop`, (7)
`comm`.

Answer (score 0):

Homework?

Anyway, I vote for`ps` as answer to question 6. The problem with question 5 has been addressed already.